# Invalid Signature Smart Contract

Tags: blockchain, solidity, ethers.js, evm

I am trying to execute the lending call function from this Smart Contract.

The following code is JavaScript using Ethers.js to make the integration with the Smart Contract.

```
const contractAddress = "0x1C4E9F87c7F2bCd80c89A1999d776461d41545b9";

    const provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider(
      "https://rpc.ankr.com/bsc"
    );
    const signer = new ethers.Wallet(privateKey, provider);
    const contract = new ethers.Contract(contractAddress, ABI, signer);

    const lending = async () => {
      const id = 992581;
      const tokenId = 16587857756452;
      const price = 500000000000;
      const expiredAt = Date.now() + 60;
    
      const messageHash = ethers.utils.solidityKeccak256(
        ["uint256", "uint256", "uint256", "uint256"],
        [id, tokenId, price, expiredAt]
      );
      const signingKey = new SigningKey("0x" + privateKey);
      const signature = signingKey.signDigest(messageHash);
      const signatureString = ethers.utils.joinSignature(signature);
    
      const tx = await contract.lending(
        id,
        tokenId,
        price,
        expiredAt,
        signatureString,
        {
          gasLimit: 50000,
        }
      );
      const receipt = await tx.wait();
    
      console.log(receipt);
    };
```

This is the trx showing the error.

The Smart Contract code that verifies the signature is this one.

```
  function verifyLendingSig(
    uint256 _id,
    uint256 _tokenId,
    uint256 _price,
    uint256 _expiredAt,
    bytes calldata _signature
  ) public view {
    bytes32 criteriaMessageHash = keccak256(
      abi.encodePacked(_id, _tokenId, _price, _expiredAt)
    );
    bytes32 ethSignedMessageHash = ECDSA.toEthSignedMessageHash(
      criteriaMessageHash
    );

    require(
      ECDSA.recover(ethSignedMessageHash, _signature) == signer,
      "invalid signature"
    );
  }
```

Can someone show me how I can generate the signature for the lending call?

Comment: is your `privateKey` valid?

Comment: @Yilmaz yes, it is

Comment: Where is `signer` in this `require(
      ECDSA.recover(ethSignedMessageHash, _signature) == signer,
      "invalid signature"
    );`

Comment: @Yilmaz sorry did not understand 
this verify function is from a smart contract I want to interact with

Comment: you are using `signer` inside `verifyLendingSig` but  I dont know where it came from?